# p2os vs ROSARIA

Tags: ros, p2os, aria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi friends,

Most of community here uses p2os for pioneer robots. ARIA library from MobileRobotics is also integrated with ROSARIA wrapper. What is the difference between them?  Are there any possible issues with pioneer controller with p2os?
[p2os](http://ros.org/wiki/p2os) do mention support ARCOS firmware. Is it fully supported? I presume yes! Just to be on safer side.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29754/p2os-vs-rosaria/) by [prince](https://answers.ros.org/users/939/prince/) on ROS Answers with karma: 660 on 2012-03-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,  the difference is that p2os contains its own implementation of the robot protocol, while ROSARIA calls into the ARIA library.  This makes ROSARIA more complex to set up and use, though it's more portable across different MobileRobots robots and configurations -- and future robots -- and it would be easier for you to add or modify it (since you just need to use the relevant ARIA API, not the robot or other device communications)

p2os however has been around a bit longer (I think it was actually adapted from Player... the name indicates it was originally developed for the old Pioneer 2 robot) and at this point I think p2os contains some features that are not yet in ROSARIA.

hope this helps,

Reed

---

Originally posted by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) with karma: 821 on 2012-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0